# Oracle DB: Map Date field type with specific format from db into the entity model field

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, spring-data

I am trying to map a field with type `Date` into my entity from Oracle DB which looks like this: `10.06.1999 10:58:45`

I've tried with different types, `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date` - they all throw exceptions while trying to read the data form db into the model.

Only `java.sql.Time` doesn't throw exceptions. It isn't suitable for my case, because the UI then only displays the time and when saving this value from UI overwrites the data in the database with time only and not date e.g: `10:58:45`.

Is it a good way to use the (new Java 8) DateTime class in the entity mode class with a formatter inside the model to tell the model to parse the date correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, depending on what exactly matches with your database, either `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` will be a recommended choice.

Comment: What exception do you get when you use `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @MehdiJavan `Can not construct instance of java.sql.Date: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('17:06:03')`

Comment: @OleV.V. so I use a DateFormatter inside my entity model? Is that considered a ok practice?

Comment: Why are you storing a datetime as text in the database?

Comment: @Kayaman It's not stored as text in the database. In the database it is 'Date'

Comment: If it's a `DATE` in database, how come it has a time component? `TIMESTAMP` contains a date and a time, `DATE` contains only the date.

Comment: I haven’t got the experience myself, but I read that you should be able to get at least one of those types directly from you `ResultSet` (using `getObject()`), so you don’t need a formatter for any conversion. It requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, which I expect that you either have or can get easily.

Comment: @Kayaman because it's an oracle db and I've been asking myself the same question, but it is what it is... :(

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm using JPA & Hibernate.

Comment: Sorry, didn’t study the tags well enough. I can’t remember exactly what I read about JPA and Hibernate. I would expect them to handle it too.

Comment: If you have a new enough Hibernate, you shouldn't need any special handling to use the new `java.time` classes. The value is in binary, but it seems that it's being converted to String as some form of last resort. However you could try if `java.sql.Timestamp` works instead of `java.sql.Date`. If that works, then it's a conversion issue (and you can get ready made components for that).

Comment: @Kayaman unfortunately the same problem `Can not deserialize value of type java.sql.Timestamp from String "17:06:03": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '17:06:03': Can not parse date "17:06:03": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map your database DATE column to java.util.Date (or other based classes) you need to add the @Temporal annotation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html

Comment: Same error `Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "17:06:03": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '17:06:03': Can not parse date "17:06:03": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))`

Comment: "java.util.Date from String "17:06:03" - Where is the "String" coming from? Is it saved in the database?

Comment: As mentioned the string is coming in as a last resort to try and convert the date. The field type in the database is `DATE` and is displayed like this: `06/10/1999 10:58:36`

Comment: I think there is a misconception. If you have saved the data into a DATE column there is no parsing to be done. It is a date in the database using its own internal representation and it is read by the JDBC driver in that format. There is no String parsing to be done.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not stored in the correct `DATE` format for java to understand it as a date..

Comment: Therefore all you have to do is annotate your field/method with @Column(name="MY_DATE_COLUMMN") @Temporal private Date myDate;. That's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153769/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-fhossfel).